# How to store Google API Client connection token in Android

Tags: android, oauth, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I'm using GoogleApiClient to connect to Google Drive and it is working perfectly fine. I'm following this tutorial.

http://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html

What i need is to Store Connection token/Credentials in the shared preferences, so that on activity resume, restart etc, I can recreate a session from the stored value instead of asking user to Login again and again.

GoogleApiClient does not have such type of function from which i can get the OAuth token etc. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) for this